# Analytically tractable solution to system to ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation-theory

I have the following system of ODEs

$$\begin{aligned} \dot x (t) & = x(t) \frac{h(t)}{h_0} - \frac{x^2(t)}{x_0} \\ \dot h(t) & = -a h(t) \end{aligned}$$

where $x(0)=x_0$ and $h(0)=h_0$.

Using Mathematica, I have found that the system yields a complicated expression for x(t) that involves the exponential integral function. In contrast, $h(t)$ is simply $h(t)=h_0e^{-at}$.

Through trial and error, I have found that, when $a$ is small, $x(t) \approx x_0e^{-at}$. However, the accuracy of this approximation decreases as $t$ increases.

I am hoping to receive suggestions regarding an analytical approximation of this system that is fairly accurate but also integrable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of information do you actually need? Much of the system's behaviour can also be seen directly from the [phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=StreamPlot%5B%7Bx%28y-x%29%2C-y%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-2%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C-2%2C2%7D%5D).

Comment: Why not use $h_0$ and $x_0$?

Comment: @HansLundmark I am hoping to acquire an integrable approximation of the x(t) function

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Use them how?

Comment: By replacing $K$ and $H$, naturally. Why are some quantities lowercase and others uppercase?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Aside from simplifying notation, would this potentially solve the problem somehow?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Updated notation

Comment: Integrable in what sense? And for what purpose? (By the way, if you use dimensionless variables $X=x/x_0$, $Y=h/h_0$ and $\tau = at$ you'll get rid of all the constants.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Integrable symbolically, as opposed to just numerically. Since Ei is not an elementary function, I cannot integrate the function from 0 to infinity. I am hoping to approximate the function so that such integration can be done

Comment: OK, so what you want to compute is $\int_0^\infty x(t) \, dt$?

Comment: Yes, apologies for not being clear about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the solution you find complicated is
$$x(t)=\frac {a x_0 e^{\frac{1-e^{-a t}}{a}} } {a+e^{\frac{1}{a}}
   \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{e^{-a
   t}}{a}\right)\right) }$$

Assuming $t>0$ and $a>0$, you can expand as a series around $a=0$ to get
$$x(t)=x_0+ x_0 \left(1-t-e^{-t}\right)\,a+\frac{1}{2}  x_0 e^{-2 t} \left(-e^t t^2+e^{2 t}
   t^2+4 e^t t-2 e^{2 t}+2\right)a^2+O\left(a^3\right)$$

The syntax is

```
        Series[x[t],{a,0,2},Assumptions-> a>0 && t>0]
```

Now,

$$f(y)=\int_0^y x(t)\,dt=x_0 \log\Bigg[1+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{a}}}{a} \left(\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{e^{-a
   y}}{a}\right)\right)\Bigg]$$ which does not converge if $y\to \infty$.

If $a$ is very small, $f(y) \sim x_0y$

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that my comment led to the orphaning of your answer.